# Given a facebook staging_resources image URI, how do I get out a usable URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can successfully upload a png to FB's staging resources via the graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api#objectapi-images-staging. This returns a URI of the form fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/XXX. The docs say:

> Although this is a URI, it's for internal use only and is only a way to pass around an identifier. Referencing it as if it were an image will not return any useful data.

I'd like to use the staged image in a share dialog for the user, but for this I need a URL. When I pass the URI to ShareLink's image param (I'm using Unity's 7.2.2 FB plugin in Unity 5.2.4 but I think this is a generic issue?) I get an error because it expects image URLs to start with http:// or https://.

Is there a way to get the URL from this staging URI? The docs are unclear.

(You can phrase your answer in terms of the graph API explorer, I don't need a C# or Unity-specific answer)

Comment: You can not use that as a dialog parameter to specify an image. You need to use it with a user-owned object.

Comment: What does 'user-owned' mean? Something created or selected from the client ?